# How can I count rows based on multiple different groups?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table structure:

```
// QandA
+----+----------------------------------------+------+---------+-----------+------------+
| Id |                   body                 | type | related | author_id | date_time  |
+----+----------------------------------------+------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 1  | content of question1                   | 0    | null    | 12345     | 1467468795 |
| 2  | content of first answer for question1  | 1    | 1       | 53456     | 1467469311 |
| 3  | content of question2                   | 0    | null    | 43634     | 1467469512 |
| 4  | content of second answer for question1 | 1    | 1       | 43665     | 1467470098 |
| 5  | content of first answer for question2  | 1    | 3       | 43324     | 1467471291 |
+----+----------------------------------------+------+---------+-----------+------------+
-- type: 0 means question, 1 means answer
-- related: null means question, else it's the id of its own question
```

I'm trying to implement this *(something exactly like what stackoverflow does)*. An user can ask:

- 1 question per 90 minute
- 6 question per day
- 50 question per month

So I need to count the number of previous question for an user before letting him to ask. How can I do that?

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO QandA (id, body, type, related, author_id, date_tiem)
SELECT NULL, :body, 0, NULL, :id, unix_timestamp
FROM QANDA
WHERE author_id = :id AND
      type = 0 AND
      /* those three conditions */
```

Comment: Search for an SQL tutorial. Study. Then try to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplification of @scaisEdge's solution removes the aggregation in the subqueries, uses scalar comparisons, and doesn't reference `QandA` in the outer query:

```
INSERT INTO QandA (id, body, type, related, author_id, date_time)
    SELECT NULL, :body, 0, NULL, :id, unix_timestamp
    FROM dual
    WHERE (select count(*)
           from QANDA  
           where date_time < unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 minute))   and
                 author_id = :id and
                 type >= 1
          ) < 1
          (select count(*)
           from QANDA  
           where date_time < unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 day)) and
                 author_id = :id and
                 type >= 1
          ) < 6
          author_id = :id AND type = 1 AND
          (select count(*)
           from QANDA  
           where date_time < unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 month  ))   and
                 author_id = :id and
                 type >= 1
          ) < 50;
```

A more efficient version only does the aggregation once:

```
INSERT INTO QandA (id, body, type, related, author_id, date_time)
    SELECT NULL, :body, 0, NULL, :id, unix_timestamp
    FROM (select count(*) as num_month,
                 coalesce(sum(date_time < unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 day)), 0) as num_day,
                 coalesce(sum(date_time < unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 minute)), 0) as num_90min
          from QANDA  
          where date_time < unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 month)) and
               author_id = :id and
               type >= 1
         ) a 
    WHERE num_month < 50 and num_day < 6 and num_90min < 1;
```

I also think this is easier to read.

Comment: In the second version: 1) Why did you use `count()` for `num_month` and `sum()` for the others? 2) Why `type >= 1`? I think it should be `type = 0` *(as I mentioned in the question, `0` means the questions, `1` means the answers)*

Comment: @stack I don't think it makes any difference. `count(*)` is just more idiomatic than `sum(1)`. But along those lines I think you'll also need to restrict the inner query to previous month. He probably accidentally left that part out.

Comment: @stack Yes, although remember that the lengths of months vary so perhaps you really intend 30 days. Up to you.

Comment: **Five problems:** 1.you are missing `)` in the end of `sum`s functions. 2.use `>` instead of `<` for this `date_time < unix_timestamp ...` part. 3.restrict the inner query to *only* previous month. 4.use `type=0` instead of `type>=1`. 5.use `count()` for all of them to make it uniform.

Comment: @stack . . . Because the `where` clause takes care of the 1 month case -- or at least it does now that I fixed it ;)

Comment: Why did you write `INTERVAL 90 minute` in the `where` clause? I guess you should write `INTERVAL 1 month` instead.

Comment: `sum()` returns `NULL` when no row selected, and then in that case, `INSERT` query fails. You have to use `count()`.

Answer (score 1):

Could be somethings lke this query

```
INSERT INTO QandA (id, body, type, related, author_id, date_tiem)
SELECT NULL, :body, 0, NULL, :id, unix_timestamp
FROM QANDA as a 

WHERE author_id = :id 
AND type = 1 
AND a.author_id not in ( select  author_id = :id
                    from QANDA  
                    where date_time < unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 90 minute  ))  
                    and  author_id = :id
                    and  type =>1
                    group by  author_id
                    having count(*) => 1  ) 
AND a.author_id not in ( select  author_id = :id
                    from QANDA  
                    where date_time < unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY   ))  
                    and  author_id = :id
                    and  type = 1
                    group by  author_id
                    having count(*) => 6  )     
AND a.author_id not in ( select  author_id = :id, count(*) 
                    from QANDA  
                    where date_time < unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH   ))  
                    and  author_id = :id
                    and  type = 1
                    group by  author_id
                    having count(*) =>  50  )
```

Be careful with not in ..check also for empty result ..

Comment: I guess you have to use `NOT EXISTS()` instead of `NOT IN()`

Comment: No  is not in  .. i check for autor_id  not in .. that paired with author_id = :id mean  :id not in .. you can also use :id not is  .. if  more clear ..

Comment: Well what about [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110565/how-can-i-limit-inserting-based-on-some-conditions)? Do you think has it better performance than yours?

Comment: I don't know .. the performance are mainly related to number of rows and indexes .. with a proper index on author_id ..both the query should be performed in some decimal of second . also with a population of 100.000 or more  rows

Comment: This query has a logic problem. You have to use `>` instead of `<` in this: `date_time < unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL ...`